# Can a flash drive be set up to detect copying?

Tags: authentication, privacy, storage

Can I prepare a flash drive in such a way that I can tell if someone copies files from it?

Comment: How would you differentiate viewing and copying?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out if someone copied a file from my external hard disk](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/99576/find-out-if-someone-copied-a-file-from-my-external-hard-disk)

Answer (score 2):

Nope. In the electronic/digital world, reading is an essential subset of copying. No way to tell the difference between the two on the storage medium.

It "could" be detected at the processing stage (i.e., on the computer where the copying is taking place) - if you have sole control on both reading and copying. That essentially rules out any standards based (compatible with other things) options.

It is possible with destinations that support DRM.

Bottomline: No, not at source.